# why ${0}×R$ is not open in $R^2$?

Tags: general-topology

${0}×R $is open in the product topology $R_d×R $(and, hence, in the dictionary topology on R×R ),  where  R_d  is   discrete topology on R .

now  my  question  is that   why ${0}×R$ is not  open  in $R^2$

Comment: Because the standard topology on $R^2$ is coarser than the dictionary topology! They are different topologies and what is open in the latter may not be open in the first one.

Comment: Well, 0 is not open in R in the standard topology, right?

Comment: Given a point $p = (0,t) \in 0 \times R$, can you find a positive number $r > 0$ such that the open ball in $R^2$ with center $p$ and radius $r$ is a subset of $0 \times R$?

Comment: @Luke,then   why  it  is open  in dictionary  topology  $R\times R $ ??

Comment: @LeeMosher...yes  we  can find its  ...

Comment: @lomber: No, you cannot find such an r as Lee Mosher said (see the answer below). And you should not be too surprised that in different topologies, different sets are considered to be open sets. Think of the topology where all sets are open...

Answer (score 1):

This was a very curious question for me when I was studying Calculus of $\mathbb{R}^n$. First $\{0\}\times\mathbb{R}$ is basically the interval $(-\infty,\infty)$ say $I$ and let $a\in I$. Then $\exists$ no $\varepsilon>0$ such that the open ball (since in $\mathbb{R}^2$ open sets are open balls) $B(a;\varepsilon)\subset I$. Hence $a$ is not an interior point of $I$. So $I$ is not open in $\mathbb{R}^2$.